# Chrome crash during Karate UI Tests in linux based container

Tags: azure-pipelines, karate, linux-containers

I am running UI tests using Karate which work totally fine in my local windows machine. However, when I try to run the same scripts using a azure pipeline in a linux based container, I get error indicating "Invalid Session". On further checking the service logs of our pipeline setup i found this error -

{"sessionId":"4f331fad5adc08ab178a9b1bd494fa12","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: session deleted because of page crash\nfrom unknown error: cannot determine loading status\nfrom tab crashed\n  (Session info: headless chrome=114.0.5735.133)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}),platform=Linux 5.15.0-1042-azure x86_64)"}}

All the steps after this crash are failing and showing invalid session error as the browser itself is getting crashed.

This happens after few UI actions when the test tries to click on buttons of a particular bar. There is no frame used. I have tried degrading the chrome/chromedriver versions. Currently I am running the tests in headless mode.

Comment: sorry it is unlikely you will get any help for this. I suggest you use a docker container so that compatibility with the enclosing os is better. karate has a docker container for chrome direct, but not for chromedriver. this is a good opportunity for you to do some more investigation and contribute findings back to the community. also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75533988/143475